# Can I create custom reports with custom dimension drill downs in GA4?

Tags: image, google-analytics, report

I am upgrading to new GA4. I want to create a new custom reports in GA4 like the ones I created in universal analytics (UA). In old analytics, when I create new custom reports, I am able to add my custom dimensions in drill-down format like this:

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDwj0.png)

I want to create a same custom report in GA4 but I am not able to add my custom dimension in drill-down format like in the old version. Is there any way to create custom report with custom dimensions like old Google analytics?

Comment: Did you find a way how to do it? I am looking for that too...